# vs2008 c#: Facebook very simple beginner application

Tags: c#, facebook

I just tried instructions on following page to get very basic app to work and its not working. Has any one tried this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd277870.aspx

at the following line

```
friendList1.Friends = facebookService1.Friends.GetUserObjects();
```

I get the following error:

```
Facebook.Utility.FacebookException was unhandled
  Message="Incorrect signature"
  Source="Facebook"
  ErrorCode=104
  StackTrace:
       at Facebook.Utility.Utilities.ParseException(String response, Boolean JSONFormat)
       at Facebook.Rest.RestBase.processResponse(WebResponse webResponse)
       at Facebook.Rest.RestBase.SendRequestSynchronous(IDictionary`2 parameterDictionary, Boolean useSession)
       at Facebook.Rest.RestBase.SendRequest[T](IDictionary`2 parameterDictionary, Boolean useSession)
       at Facebook.Rest.Friends.GetUserObjects(Int64 uid, Int64 flid, Boolean isAsync, GetInfoCallback callback, Object state)
       at Facebook.Rest.Friends.GetUserObjects(Int64 uid, Int64 flid)
       at Facebook.Rest.Friends.GetUserObjects()
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\ZULFIQAR SYED\Local Settings\Application Data\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 33
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in C:\Documents and Settings\ZULFIQAR SYED\Local Settings\Application Data\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Does Microsoft Facebook API work at all? Am I wasting my time?

Comment: In order to help you: can you provide some information (by extending/editing the question) about what you have done, including error messages?

Comment: What's the problem you're having with the API? Your question is vague.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986408/visual-studio-2008-c-facebook-very-simple-beginner-application

Comment: More info needed... what exactly isn't working? What errors?

Comment: I just added the following 4 lines and the tutorial in the link works.

string apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

facebookService1.ApplicationKey = apikey;

facebookService1.ConnectToFacebook();

friendList1.Friends = facebookService1.Friends.GetUserObjects();

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this yet?

**Facebook Developer Wiki**
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:C_Sharp

It assumes only basic knowledge of Facebook and C#

Comment: Consider posting another question with the problem you are having, and the exact wording of the error message.  Maybe it's something simple.